# How can I combine multiple Ninja logs/deps into a single one?

Tags: cmake, gitlab-ci, ninja

TL;DR: I want to build several Ninja targets in their respective different GitLab CI jobs, then recombine their results and create the last target *without* recompiling all previous artifacts. How can I do that?

---

I have a (rather large) CMake project at hand that takes ages to compile. In order to speed things up, I would like to compile several internal libraries in parallel on different GitLab CI runners (none of them have multiple cores). This already works fine, however, the last executable that needs those internal libraries recompiles everything again:

```
           ,--> libawesome.a  ,
libbase.a {---> libcontrol.a   }--> app
           `--> liboverflow.a ´
```

Within GitLab CI, the creation of the libs works fine and in parallel:

```
base:
   script:
     - cmake -B build -GNinja .
     - cmake --build build --target libbase.a
   artifacts:
     paths:
       - build/

internal libs:
   needs: ["base"]
   parallel:
     matrix:
       - LIB: [awesome, control, overflow]
   script:
     - cmake --build build --target lib${LIB}.a
   artifacts:
     paths:
       - build/${LIB}   # this is a subdirectory project
```

This works as expected: the `internal libs` do not recompile `base`, they only compile a handful of targets, no duplicate compilation.

However, the following job recompiles almost everything:

```
application:
   needs: ["base", "internal libs"]
   script:
     - cmake --build build --target application
```

This more or less defeats the purpose of the `internal libs` job, as the CI pipeline will then take as long as it would need to compile the whole project from scratch (except for `base` and maybe one of the libraries).

I've already tried to store the respective `build/.ninja_log`s and concatenate them before using `cmake --build`, but that doesn't work. It seems like Ninja has some kind of internal storage that doesn't properly get merged by the simple file copy operations that GitLab's CI system does.

Is there a way to merge those multiple runs?